# How to find out what group a given user has?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, system-administration

In Unix/Linux, how do you find out what group a given user is in via command line?

Comment: To get the opposite, see who is in a given group, you can use `getent group <groupname>`.

Comment: @iconoclast : which doesn’t list users belonging to the group in /etc/passwd.

Answer (score 413, accepted):

```
groups
```

or

```
groups user
```

Answer (score 110):

This one shows the user's uid as well as all the groups (with their gids) they belong to

```
id userid
```

Comment: This appears to be pretty useful as well. It has more verbose output than the 'groups' command, so if you need the group id/user id use this!

Comment: This should be the most detailed and correct answer, have an upvote!

Answer (score 19):

On Linux/OS X/Unix to display the groups to which you (or the optionally specified user) belong, use:

```
id -Gn [user]
```

which is equivalent to `groups [user]` utility which has been obsoleted on Unix.

On OS X/Unix, the command `id -p [user]` is suggested for normal interactive.

Explanation on the parameters:

> `-G`, `--groups` - print all group IDs
>
> `-n`, `--name` - print a name instead of a number, for `-ugG`
>
> `-p` - Make the output human-readable.

Comment: `-p` would be super useful in GNU id.

Answer (score 0):

or just study /etc/groups (ok this does probably not work if it uses pam with ldap)

Comment: Indeed, that's a bad answer. 'getent group' is a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the script which is integrated into ansible and generating dashboard in CSV format.

```
sh collection.sh

#!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME=`hostname -s`

for i in `cat /etc/passwd| grep -vE "nologin|shutd|hal|sync|root|false"|awk -F':' '{print$1}' | sed 's/[[:space:]]/,/g'`; do groups $i; done|sed s/\:/\,/g|tr -d ' '|sed -e "s/^/$HOSTNAME,/"> /tmp/"$HOSTNAME"_inventory.txt

sudo cat /etc/sudoers| grep -v "^#"|awk '{print $1}'|grep -v Defaults|sed '/^$/d;s/[[:blank:]]//g'>/tmp/"$HOSTNAME"_sudo.txt

paste -d , /tmp/"$HOSTNAME"_inventory.txt /tmp/"$HOSTNAME"_sudo.txt|sed 's/,[[:blank:]]*$//g' >/tmp/"$HOSTNAME"_inventory_users.txt
```

My output stored in below text files.

```
cat /tmp/ANSIBLENODE_sudo.txt
cat /tmp/ANSIBLENODE_inventory.txt
cat /tmp/ANSIBLENODE_inventory_users.txt
```