# Is there a command to list all Unix group names?

Tags: linux

I know there is the `/etc/group` file that lists all users groups.

I would like to know if there is a simple command to list all user group names in spite of parsing the world readable `/etc/group` file. I am willing to create an administrator web page that lists Linux accounts' group names.

Comment: So far he tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059916/there-is-a-command-to-list-all-unix-group-names

Comment: "I willing to create a web page that lists Linux users" - what problem are you trying to solve?  This sounds like something that may cause some security problems (exposing list of users, exposing credentials).

Comment: I was trying to give an simple example. I would like to open an "administrator system web page to list current Linux accounts names". In Linux I could find commands to add a user, remove a user, change a user, find the groups of a given user but did not found a command to search a user by name fragment. I think the question is not so irrelevant. All I could do to rememebr a Linux group account was to do a lookup on /etc/group file

Comment: Similar: [How do you find out what group a given user is in via command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/350141/55075)

Answer (score 922, accepted):

To list all local groups which have users assigned to them, use this command:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/group | sort
```

For more info- >
[Unix groups](http://www.udel.edu/it/help/unix/unixgroups.html),
[Cut command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cut-command-linux-examples/),
[sort command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-command-linuxunix-examples/)

Comment: Yes MichaelIT is right the groups command did not list all groups. I asked this because unsure if there is a simple command like groups to lists all groups names or even a swith to it like groups [-a|--all] to list all system groups without doing file scan.

Comment: ok so for now the answer is NO. Need to use text editing to filter group file.

Comment: What is "cut -d: -f1"?

Comment: @zed `cut` is another command which extracts the specific column from an input. Here I'm extracting field 1 where fields are delimited by `:`

Answer (score 295):

If you want *all groups* known to the system, I would recommend using `getent group` instead of parsing `/etc/group`:

```
getent group
```

The reason is that on networked systems, groups may not only read from `/etc/group` file, but also obtained through LDAP or Yellow Pages (the list of known groups comes from the local group file plus groups received via LDAP or YP in these cases).

If you want just the group names you can use:

```
getent group | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: For some usecases a sorted list of group names might be preferable: `getent group | cut -d: -f1 | sort`

Comment: If numbered lines are desirable, do `getent group | cut -d: -f1 | sort | cat -n`.

Comment: great point for networked systems like LDAP!

Comment: @dasup do you know how to create ID that will only assign local group not from LDAP in case of networked system.

Comment: Need some explanation for the output format.

Answer (score 55):

On Linux, macOS and Unix to display the groups to which you belong, use:

```
id -Gn
```

which is equivalent to `groups` utility which has been obsoleted on Unix (as per [Unix manual](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/groups/)).

On macOS and Unix, the command `id -p` is suggested for normal interactive.

Explanation of the parameters:

> `-G`, `--groups` - print all group IDs
>
> `-n`, `--name` - print a name instead of a number, for `-ugG`
>
> `-p` - Make the output human-readable.

Comment: And `id -Gn someusername` returns the list of groups for the specified user.

Comment: `id -Gnz | xargs -0 -I% echo %` will list each group on a separate line. This is useful if the group names have spaces in them.

Comment: How is `groups` obsolete? Any sources? I searched "unix groups command obsolete" but did not find anything.

Comment: @FranklinYu It's in the [BSD manual page for `groups`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/groups/).

Comment: Doest answer original question pertaining to groups outside of current user.

Comment: @MarkLakata use `tr '\0' '\n'` instead of `xargs`.