# Can't change a file's group owner in Cygwin

Tags: unix, cygwin

I'm trying to do:

```
chown :Users filename
```

And I get

> chown: invalid grup: «:Users»

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to keep the same user and change the group, saying `chown :group` instead of `chown user:group`.

The syntax is wrong, so you can either use `chown` indicating the current user or directly use `chgrp` instead:

```
chgrp Users filename
```

Comment: Does the group `Users` even exist? You can check it in `/etc/group` by saying for example `awk -F: '$1=="Users"' /etc/group`.

Comment: @ fedorqui It says "no such file or directory /etc/group".

Comment: Then the problem is in the group name itself. You may be able to see all the groups by saying `groups`, as indicated in [Is there a command to list all Unix group names?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14060177/1983854)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
chgrp Users /path/to/filename
```

PS: keep in mind that "Users" is different of "users".