# Fetch all groups from Linux using Java

Tags: java, linux

I want to fetch all groups available on Linux machine using Java. Can someone tell me which Java API I can use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to give up on the portability of your app(Linux only instead of cross platform deployment) you could do a system call, where you combine [the calling of a command line function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java) with [the groups command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059916/is-there-a-command-to-list-all-unix-group-names)

Comment: is there any direct way for pulling all groups instead of  calling command ?

Comment: I think not, but I could be mistaken, as I understand it, java compiles to javacode and that runs on a java virtual machine on your linux machine. That JVM interprets the javacode to machine instructions, since your java code can also run on windows,where there might not be groups, a "getgroups" function isn't available inside the javacode,java itself and thus not in the java virtual machine(since it would never be called) .