# Is it possible to install a Vagrant plugin per project?

Tags: vagrant

Is it possible to install a Vagrant plugin locally, per project, so that different projects may have different plugins or different versions of the same plugin installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 4 issues related to that on Vagrant's issue tracker but all of them are closed as it seems that @mitchellh [does not have plans to support that from Vagrant's core on the short term](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1574#issuecomment-23196908):

- [GH-1874](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1874)
- [GH-1789](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1789)
- [GH-1700](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1700)
- [GH-1574](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1574)

For now I believe that the only way to do that is to use [bindler](https://github.com/fgrehm/bindler). The idea is to eventually implement a "full blown [Bundler](http://bundler.io/)" for Vagrant but for now you should be able to have plugins installed per project alongside global plugins installations.

Just keep in mind that it is **highly experimental** and things might go wrong :)

**UPDATE: Bindler has been deprecated and is incompatible with recent Vagrant versions**