# How to use vagrant in a proxy environment?

Tags: proxy, vagrant, http-proxy

My company's network is using proxy. So when I use `vagrant up`, it showed me a 401 permission error.

How can I do some setting to use vagrant?

Comment: Sorry,I didn't.Now I know `vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf`.

Comment: But after I installed and setted my proxy url to config file,the result was the same.401

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Install proxyconf:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

Configure your Vagrantfile:

```
config.proxy.http     = "http://yourproxy:8080"
config.proxy.https    = "http://yourproxy:8080"
config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: `config.env_proxy.*` is deprecated as of version 2.0 and has been replaced by `config.proxy.*`.

Comment: `config.proxy.https = "https://yourproxy:8080"` is that `https` or `http` in the second line

Comment: it could be both. In my company http and https goes through the same proxy which is in http

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the proxy is cntlm running on that machine. There could be a work around, but I just pointed to another machine and it worked.

Comment: re: eldos, the url for https_proxy is http://server:port/ (https proxy requests are really a http CONNECT request that opens the tunnel, so the proxy server is accessed by http)

Comment: Ok when I run 'vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf' it hits my proxy ?

Comment: Answer by l.cotonea is wholistic. Set the proxy first and then install plugin.

Comment: Tried this, but got `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'config' for main:Object`

Comment: Seems you need to put `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|` before these three lines and `end` after them, to get it to work

Comment: Just one thing to mention, if you are behind a proxy, you can't install plugins.

Comment: @user3426711 you'll have to play around that. In my case I had two networks, one I needed to use for work with the proxy in there, and another one with no proxy which I could use to download whatever I needed

Answer (score 99):

If your proxy requires authentication it is better to set the environment variable rather than storing your password in the Vagrantfile.
Also your Vagrantfile can be used by others easily who are not behind a proxy.

**For Mac/Linux (in Bash)**

```
export http_proxy="http://user:password@host:port"
export https_proxy="http://user:password@host:port"
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

then

```
export VAGRANT_HTTP_PROXY=${http_proxy}
export VAGRANT_HTTPS_PROXY=${https_proxy}
export VAGRANT_NO_PROXY="127.0.0.1"
vagrant up
```

**For Windows use set instead of export.**

```
set http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
set https_proxy=https://user:password@host:port
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

then

```
set VAGRANT_HTTP_PROXY=%http_proxy%
set VAGRANT_HTTPS_PROXY=%https_proxy%
set VAGRANT_NO_PROXY="127.0.0.1"
vagrant up
```

Comment: Also, if you don't want it staying in your environment, you can do VAGRANT_HTTP_PROXY="http://user:password@host:port" vagrant up (without the export or set) for that environment variable on only one command.

Comment: Great solution as it does not require putting the proxy settings in the Vagrantfile where they clearly do not belong

Comment: Windows Powersehell v6.0:
$env:http_proxy="http://user:password@host:port"
$env:https_proxy="http://user:password@host:port"
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf

Comment: For those using Windows Git Bash, use the Mac/Linux (in Bash) instructions .e.g: export http_proxy="http://user:password@host:port"

Comment: For what it's worth, just to note that as of this writing (02/11/2018), and context being running on Windows 10 and plain CMD prompt, the "vagrant box add" command for me required the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables to also be set to work correctly.  This despite some other commands (vagrant plugin install, vagrant login) working fine with just the lower case variables being set.

Comment: You forgot (?) to `export VAGRANT_HTTPS_PROXY=${https_proxy}` in the Mac/Linux instructions.

Answer (score 53):

Installing proxyconf will solve this, but behind a proxy you can't install a plugin simply using the command `vagrant plugin install`, Bundler will raise an error.

set your proxy in your environment if you're using a unix like system

```
export http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
```

or get a more detailed answer here: [How to use bundler behind a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877055/how-to-use-bundler-behind-a-proxy)

after this set up proxyconf

Comment: On windows I did what you suggest but used "SET" instead of "export". Worked as expected without making any changes to the Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 29):

Auto detect your proxy settings and inject them in all your vagrant VM

install the proxy plugin

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
```

add this conf to you private/user VagrantFile (it will be executed for all your projects) :

```
vi $HOME/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile
```

---

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  puts "proxyconf..."
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    puts "find proxyconf plugin !"
    if ENV["http_proxy"]
      puts "http_proxy: " + ENV["http_proxy"]
      config.proxy.http     = ENV["http_proxy"]
    end
    if ENV["https_proxy"]
      puts "https_proxy: " + ENV["https_proxy"]
      config.proxy.https    = ENV["https_proxy"]
    end
    if ENV["no_proxy"]
      config.proxy.no_proxy = ENV["no_proxy"]
    end
  end
end
```

---

now up your VM !

Comment: I like this answer because it reuses the existing HTTP_PROXY env variables that I've already declared on my host OS.  Death to cut-paste !!

Comment: Looks like a good way forward.  What about disabling it when going outside the proxy?  Found that the vagrant plugin punched the guest linux in multiple places to make various different tools/apps work.  Is there a simple way to disable?  Such that will also be at least flipped from command line flag and a single `vagrant reload` will fix, and could be best to detect proxy settings in/out automatically on connecting to new networks, and either alert the user, or make it seamlessly work.  http://tmatilai.github.io/vagrant-proxyconf/ mentioned disabling, but not sure it addresses these points.

Comment: Not sure to understand but this snippet test the existence of the http_proxy env var to setup the proxy plugin. If you do not use *_proxy env it should be 'not activated' (?)

Answer (score 11):

***On a Windows host***

open a CMD prompt;

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.yourcorp.com:80
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.yourcorp.com:443
```

Substitute the address and port in the above snippets to whatever is appropriate for your situation. The above will remain set until you close the CMD prompt. If it works for you, consider adding them permanently to your environment variables so that you won't have to set them every time you open a new CMD prompt.

Answer (score 9):

**On windows**, you must set a variable to specify proxy settings, download the vagrant-proxyconf plugin: (replace {PROXY_SCHEME}(http:// or https://), {PROXY_IP} and {PROXY_PORT} by the right values)

```
set http_proxy={PROXY_SCHEME}{PROXY_IP}:{PROXY_PORT}
set https_proxy={PROXY_SCHEME}{PROXY_IP}:{PROXY_PORT}
```

After that, you can add the plugin to hardcode your proxy settings in the vagrant file

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf --plugin-source http://rubygems.org
```

and then you can provide config.proxy.xxx settings in your Vagrantfile to be independent against environment settings variables

Comment: Just an additionnal parameter (rubygem from https to http) to avoid error while verifying SSL certificates: `vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf --plugin-source http://rubygems.org` [src](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2671)

Comment: this is better solution than the previous ones, because this one doesn't need anything else. Other solutions (install a plugin) need to set free internet access first in order to do so.

Answer (score 6):

You will want to install the plugin proxyconf since this makes configuring the proxy for the guest machines pretty straight forward in the VagrantFile

```
config.proxy.http     = "http://proxy:8888"
config.proxy.https    = "http://proxy:8883"
config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

However, there's quite a few things that could still go wrong.
Firstly, you probably can't install vagrant plugins when behind the  proxy. If that's the case you should download the source e.g. from rubygems.org and install from source

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf --plugin-source file://fully/qualified/path/vagrant-proxyconf-1.x.0.gem
```

If you solve that problem you might have the fortune of being behind an NTLM proxy, which means that if you are using *nix on your guest machines then you still have some way to go, because NTLM authentication is not supported natively
There are many ways of solving that. I've used CNTLM to solve tht part of the puzzle. It acts as glue between standard authorization protocols and NTLM

For a complete walk through, have a look at [this blog entry](http://runefs.com/2014/11/28/setting-up-vagrant-behind-a-corporate-proxy/) about setting vagrant up behind a corporate proxy

Comment: I would be interested in knowing why this was down voted. It explains how to solve the issue and also how to solve potential other issues you might encounter

Comment: isn't this pretty much the same answer already provided multiple times? in addition, it doesn't say what to do to get vagrant plugins if you're behing corporate proxy, it just states that it would be a problem and then linking elsewhere.

Comment: Looks like now it should be `vagrant plugin install file://fully/qualified/path/vagrant-proxyconf-1.x.0.gem`. [Source](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/plugin.html#plugin-install)

Comment: Great idea to use `plugin-source` to install from a local GEM, but I haven't managed to get this working yet on Windows. I am not sure if my syntax is wrong, like `file://C:/path1/path2/vagrant-proxyconf-1.5.2.gem`? I have also tried the approach which @Martin mentioned above, this also didn't work as it's still trying to contact rubygems in that case

Comment: This worked for me: `vagrant plugin install C:/folder1/folder2/vagrant-proxyconf-1.5.2.gem --plugin-clean-sources` The key is `--plugin-clean-sources` which causes it to not try to access rubygems

Answer (score 2):

The question does not mention the VM Provider but in my case, I use Virtual Box under the same environment. There is an option in the Virtual Box GUI that I needed to enable in order to make it work. Is located in the Virtual Box app preferences: **File >> Preferences... >> Proxy**. Once I configured this, I was able to work without problems. Hope this tip can also help you guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually do want your proxy configurations and plugin installations to be in your Vagrantfile, for example if you're making a Vagrantfile just for your corporate environment and can't have users editing environment variables, this was the answer for me:

```
ENV['http_proxy']  = 'http://proxyhost:proxyport'
ENV['https_proxy'] = 'http://proxyhost:proxyport'

# Plugin installation procedure from http://stackoverflow.com/a/28801317
required_plugins = %w(vagrant-proxyconf)

plugins_to_install = required_plugins.select { |plugin| not Vagrant.has_plugin? plugin }
if not plugins_to_install.empty?
  puts "Installing plugins: #{plugins_to_install.join(' ')}"
  if system "vagrant plugin install #{plugins_to_install.join(' ')}"
    exec "vagrant #{ARGV.join(' ')}"
  else
    abort "Installation of one or more plugins has failed. Aborting."
  end
end

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.proxy.http     = "#{ENV['http_proxy']}"
  config.proxy.https    = "#{ENV['https_proxy']}"
  config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
  # and so on
```

(If you don't, just set them as environment variables like the other answers say and refer to them from env in config.proxy.http(s) directives.)

Answer (score 1):

Some Special characters in the password create problem in proxy. Either escape them or avoid having special characters in password.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, you could set the *http_proxy* and *https_proxy* environment variables like so:

```
$env:http_proxy="http://proxy:3128"
$env:https_proxy="http://proxy:3128"
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS Windows this works for us:

```
set http_proxy=< proxy_url >
set https_proxy=< proxy_url >
```

And the equivalent for *nix:

```
export http_proxy=< proxy_url >
export https_proxy=< proxy_url >
```