# How can I fix the HTTP Error 417 Expectation failed on Laravel's Homestead?

Tags: php, http, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm taking over the development of a php project using Laravel framework and beanstalkd driver for queuing jobs. This application was passed from a Mac development environment (that runs a beanstalkd driver) to a Windows 7 environment (beanstalkd not available for Windows machine -- at least not without cygwin tricks). So I've decided to use Vagrant homestead vm on VirtualBox that comes with an entire set of tools and servers including beanstalkd.

The application runs fine on my localhost until I try to send form data through POST header. I kept getting a "417 Expectation failed" HTTP error. I read [somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872591/how-to-use-vagrant-in-a-proxy-enviroment) that there maybe an issue with my proxy and could be fixed by disabling it. But as I see it, no proxy is used in my host machine -- I don't know about the guest (vm) though.

Could anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Does your log mention anything?

Comment: On my chrome console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 417 (Expectation Failed)". I'm using angularJs for front-end and laravel for back-end. Back-end works fine since no errors were logged in laravel. looks like something's blocking the requests.

Comment: make sure your permissions on files in your web directory are OK

Comment: My entire project folder is set "chmod -R 775"