# "NameError: undefined local variable or method 'config' for main:Object" when trying to set Vagrant proxy

Tags: vagrant

I'm very new to Vagrant (just installed it yesterday). And I am trying to set my proxy settings as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21306809/191761). I have already installed the `proxyconf` plugin.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit. I assumed that the `Vagrantfile` in question was `C:\Users\<my username>\.vagrant.d\Vagrantfile`. This file did not exist, so I created it with the contents set to just the three lines given in the answer linked above (with `yourproxy` replaced by my actual proxy of course):

> ```
> config.proxy.http     = "http://yourproxy:8080"
> config.proxy.https    = "http://yourproxy:8080"
> config.proxy.no_proxy = "localhost,127.0.0.1"
> ```

Now I am trying to run a Vagrant command (which I got from another online tutorial)

`vagrant box add bento/centos-7 --provider=virtualbox`

When I run it, I get the following:

```
There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: C:/Users/<my username>/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile
Line number: 0
Message: NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
```

Sorry as this is probably down to my extremely limited knowledge of Vagrant, but can someone help me as to how to set it up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to put `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|` before these lines and `end` after them. This is missed from the answer which I was quoting from.