# why am I getting error on adding vagrant box

Tags: vagrant

I am getting an error on adding vagrant box

and this is the error.......

The box 'ubuntu/focal64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/focal64"]
Error: The requested URL returned error: 404

Comment: Is this related to `git` somehow?

Comment: @eftshift0 I am doing a project and to answer it, I have to install and use vagrant

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because from the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply disable your antivirus for a while and run your program again this will do the trick. I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to contact this URL directly through the browser. You will be able to see the UI message with a detailed description. Your company may be using a proxy. Or you are in a country where Vagrant is not available.

[How to use vagrant in a proxy environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872591/how-to-use-vagrant-in-a-proxy-environment)