# how to detect from a Vagrantfile if a plugin has been installed?

Tags: vagrant

I would like to detect if a plugin has been installed, so I can add some useful debugging tips for users.

I have tried the following code:

```
  if config.vbguest
    config.vbguest.auto_update = true
  else
    puts "installing vagrant-vbguest plugin is recommended"
  end
```

However, Vagrant outputs `* Unknown configuration section 'vbguest'.`

Is there a way I can detect whether a plugin has been installed?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The [Vagrant.has_plugin?(name)](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/v1.3.0/lib/vagrant.rb#L138) method returns true if a plugin has been installed.

Example:

```
unless Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-some-plugin")
  raise 'some-plugin is not installed!'
end
```

Original source: [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19507570/1033422).