# Installing Xcode on Mac OSX (Yosemite)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, macos

I posted this question on Apple's forum, but it wasn't allowed for some reason. I've already seen "[Installing gem or updating RubyGems fails with permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error)", which is where I first learned about rbenv.

I'm confused because I'm new to Ruby, rbenv, and Apple's command line developer tools/XCode and don't really understand what's going on.

After typing a command into Terminal, I got the following message:

> The "xcrun" command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?

The options are "Install" and "Get Xcode."

I'm not sure which one to choose, because I don't understand all the pros and cons. I need Ruby because I'm working with Bootstrap, and I apparently need XCode (or command line tools) to work with Ruby.

My instincts say go with Xcode, as it's presumably specially designed for this kind of thing. Would that be the best choice? I just want to make sure I don't start off on the wrong foot and mess up something in my system, as others have done.

Comment: I would go with Xcode. I remember when trying to install pygame it needed the command line tools, and when I got Xcode, it worked (Except for I still don't have Xcode because of some dependency I don't have). And then you might need other things and stuff. But, it's only my opinion.

Comment: Good point. I checked MarsAtomic's response as the right answer, and chose the "command line tools" option. However, I am wondering if I might later find XCode useful for other projects. I'll just let it be for now, but if I do later find a need for XCode, should I just download it from the Apple Store and install it, or do I need to uninstall command line tools first?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about that. I'm pretty sure just get Xcode from the App Store should be fine though. But, I guess you can always check first. :) You could find Xcode later if your programming in something like C or Objective-C (If those are the languages for OSX and iOS applications) but then you might find it useful for other things too. You just have to keep you mind open!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at "[Xcode Command Line Tools](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html)" on Rails and XCode Command Line Tools.

XCode is a full blown development environment for Apple native-development. You don't need all of that overhead for Ruby or Rails, so go with the Command Line Tools to get just what you need.

Your situation might be analogous to doing an installation of Eclipse IDE in order to run some Java software that really only needs a Java Runtime Engine installation to run.