# How could i install gem in ssh without admin rights

Tags: ruby, ssh, rubygems, admin

I dont have admit rights in ssh machine so i could not install any gem

```
gem install json
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1    directory.
```

is there any ways to install it without admin rights?

Comment: Possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install --user-install json
```

This will attempt to install the gem into ~/.gem/[some subdirectory], which you should be able to write to. (By default `gem` is trying to write to /var, which you don't have permission to write as a non-admin.)

Note that you will have to append the location the gem is installed to to your PATH variable to use it (on install you should get a warning to that effect). See [this blog post about --user-install](http://www.binarytides.com/quick-tip-installing-ruby-gems-in-the-users-home-directory/) for more info