# cocoapods don't generate workspace

Tags: ios, cocoapods, realm

I'm quite New to ios and cocoapods.
I am using realm.io swift version. Everything is latest version including xcode, realm and cocoapods

I did it with dynamic linking and realised itunes don't accept the strips framework.sh ...so I try using cocoapods. I didn't remove the dynamic linking and followed the steps using cocoapods to install realm.

It generated the workspace file for me and the running keeps telling realm object can't be found though I have import realm.

So I decided to remove the previous dynamic linking and install cocoapods to start all over again.

Now cocoapods don't generate workspace for me.even a new project that I created.

I tried all the comments to remove pod, cocoapod and even clone the cocoapods etc but nothing works

Please help. Why it don't generate workspace for me anymore

I followed these steps but still don't work
https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/pod-install-error-in-terminal-not-creating-xcode-workspace

Comment: Can you post terminal output after `pod install` ?

Comment: hi Jakub, the pod install in the project directory is as following. I'm really puzzled as to why it's not generating.

MacBook-Pro:projectworld steven$ pod install

Analyzing dependencies

Downloading dependencies

Installing Realm (0.92.3)

Installing RealmSwift (0.92.3)

[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; this feature is still in beta. Add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it.

MacBook-Pro:projectworld steven$

Comment: the pod file is as following:

target 'projectworld' do
use_frameworks!
end

target 'projectworldTests' do
pod 'RealmSwift'
end

Comment: you can refer to realm swift on cocoa pods as following

http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: As per the documentation, you need to add use_frameworks! in your Tests target as well. See if that works. :)

Comment: I thought I read it use framework is my target App then the use realm is in test. I'll try it out. :)

Comment: Hi Jakub, you were right. It works flawlessly now.

Comment: Work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30800447/1442541

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481926/using-cocoapods-in-xcode-7-3/41584950#41584950

Answer (score 5):

Just copying from the comments: the answer was to specify `use_frameworks!` to the test target.

Comment: I have no error, but it still does not generate the .xcworkspace. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I was getting an **Abort:6** error during the *Generating Pods project* step of pod install.

I deleted the Pods folder, reinstalled Cocoapods, ran `pod install` again, and it worked.

Reinstall cocoapods:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 4):

I used all of the given solution and get success.

First got to **Product->Scheme->ManageScheme** and then check the shared box(Selected Form)
now **pod install**
if problem still arise
Try this

```
pod setup
pod install
```

if still have problem.(this worked for me)

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods 
pod setup
pod install
```

if problem still there then last but not least

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods 
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
pod install
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've done all the above steps and if it's still not working, try

`pod install --repo-update`

I tried all the above steps, and still it was generating pod folders with blank dependency names. This step should download all the required dependencies for your project and will also create the .xcworkspace

Answer (score 1):

To generate a workspace you must have the installer line in your Podfile saying:

`integrate_targets => true`

like this:

`install! 'cocoapods', :integrate_targets => true`

If you are using frameworks you do not need the workspace generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`use_frameworks!`

between the platform line and the target line, then redo `pod install` from your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I did

> rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/

After that it worked again.

Comment: While that command may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
rm Podfile
rm -r Pods
pod setup
pod init 
pod install //running it with 0 dependencies
pod install //running it with dependencies added
```

I could do this since I only had 2 dependencies. **Be careful if you have other dependencies.**