# Unable to install Rails due to issue with permissions on my MAC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, installation

I am trying to install rails following the instructions on this [site](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite), but I get an error when I key in the following command:

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.4
```

The error is

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory
```

I have read the related post on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error), but am unsure of what exactly to do to rectify my situation...

Comment: You problem has already been addressed in the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error) you referred.

Comment: yes, but it has been addressed, but I am confused on what exactly to do like I said in my post

Comment: How exactly did you install ruby?

Comment: based on the instructions on the site I posted above...pasting the exact content here....brew install rbenv ruby-build

# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.2.3
rbenv global 2.2.3
ruby -v

Comment: can you show the output of `which ruby`?

Comment: What I get is /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89994/discussion-between-usmanali-and-roy).

Answer (score 0):

Read the question again and its solution (the question you reffered in the description).

I will try to explain the reason why its giving you errors.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
```

In this directory your operating system has a certain version of Ruby installed. The system might require it for some purposes so normal users are not allowed to modify this directory. If you do it you might end up breaking up something without knowing.

Does this means you can not install it on your machine?
No, you can but not in this directory. Again in the question op gives the option of looking into :

```
"Instead, I'll strongly suggest you look into using either rbenv or RVM to manage a separate Ruby, "
```

one of these should do it for you.

You might want to try this with vagrant. I found it pretty convenient to test new development environment without trying to break anything on my system. 
Here is a link about trying rails in vagrant:

https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development

Comment: thanks for explaining, I am indeed using rbenv. So why do I still have issues? Basically I am following this site's instructions closely https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite

Comment: @Roy have your tried the command with sudo? for eg "sudo gem install rails -v 4.2.4". This will ask you for a password which should be your login password. This should give you permissions to overwrite the directory. you are trying to do

Comment: @Roy read more about sudo here if you have not tried this before https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202035