# gem install git-up no longer working in El Capitan

Tags: git, osx-elcapitan

After upgrating to OS "El Capitan" I noticed that git-up was no longer installed. I tried to install by:

```
~  gem install git-up
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/git-up-0.5.12/bin/git-up
~
```

Mal El Capitan

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After digging in I found the directory is owned by a user other than myself. (/Library/Ruby/Gems/.. is installed by Apple as part of Mac OS X.)

So I simply used brew to get install my own ruby and bingo!

```
~  brew update
~  brew install ruby
```

Then I could run:

```
~  gem install git-up
...
6 gems installed
```

I started this post as a question but ended with a solution. I hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, on OS 10.11.5. After `brew install ruby` I had to explicitly call `/usr/local/bin/gem install <whatever>`. Beats me why, because `which gem` points there already.

Comment: @Ian It helps to restart the terminal after installing ruby (even though `which gem` already seems to point to the right location).

Comment: This didn't work on  mac 10.10.5  which ruby points to /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: @vikramvi did you try lab's suggestion to restart terminal, it was required before it would work for me.

Comment: I also had the issue that @Ian reported, but it was fixed by simply closing and reopening the terminal window.

Comment: You could just do `sudo gem install sass`, and voila!

Comment: Only `brew install ruby` command doesn't solve the problem with permissions for gem packages. The root of issue that by default macOS used system ruby binary, so that cause problems when you try to build and store some gem package by system ruby. So, like a solution, I used a `rbenv` to install a custom ruby binary only for my $HOME user. After installing and setup rbenv ruby version, you can update all gems with this one by `gem update --system`

Comment: I still get You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory

Answer (score 1):

The solution worked for me big time

- git-up-0.5.12
- Installing ri documentation for git-up-0.5.12
- Done installing documentation for diff-lcs, mime-types, posix-spawn, grit, colored, git-up after 7 seconds
- 6 gems installed