# How do I get Sass to work on mac using Scout?

Tags: css, ruby, macos, permissions, sass

I have just installed [Scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/) on my iMac for processing Sass (for my new Drupal Zen sub theme) into css, I keep getting errors, basically,  after it detects a change to a SASS file it won't convert to CSS - the CSS file remains unchanged. I have also installed Homebrew in order to install Ruby as well as I thought it could be a permission problem as indicated by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error) , but this didn't help and I still get the problem. I have checked on my terminal session that inline_image.rb (listed below) exists but has file permission -rwxr-xr-x@. Can anyone help?

This is the error log:

```
Change detected at 18:32:00 to: styles-rtl.scss
Compass::Error on line 61 of /Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/inline_image.rb: File not found or cannot be read: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wib/menu-collapsed-rtl.png
/Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/inline_image.rb:6:in `inline_image'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2096:in `send' /Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/script/funcall.rb:106:in `_perform' /Applications/Scout.app/Contents/Resources/vendor/gems/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib/sass/script/node.rb:40:in `perform'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image declared in your css (styles-rtl.scss) is not found in the images directory. This is the key part of the error `File not found or cannot be read: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wib/menu-collapsed-rtl.png`

Compass will look for all images declared in the directory listed in the `config.rb` file. You may have to do some detective work to ensure you have the correct path to your images and the images are in that folder. In this case you will have to copy them from the Zen base theme images directory.

Comment: i found the problem thanks to your response above which got me looking in the right direction. Basically, I had not specified the Images folder location in Scout in the Images configuration field ( I had left it blank). Once I did this it worked perfectly - many thanks for helping.