# Rails installation fails in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install Rails on Ubuntu, but it is showing the following error:

`ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory.`

Please help me to install the Rails gem.

Comment: Try: sudo gem install rails

Comment: Try this blog [Installing Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu](http://installroronubuntu.blogspot.in/) It will guide you in setting up for system to full

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing gem or updating RubyGems fails with permissions error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error)

Comment: it is showing this - sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 1):

```
Run This Command
sudo gem update --system
```