# Installing Rubymine Debugger IDE after setting up rbenv global 2.1.2?

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine, rbenv

I've been trying to set up the debugger in Rubymine 2016.3. The initial error I was receiving stated that I didn't have permission to write in the version of ruby already installed in my mac os.

So I downloaded rbenv and set up a new ruby 2.1.2 environment by using `rbenv global 2.1.2` and checking to make sure it was being used with `ruby -v`.

After selecting 2.1.2 default in preferences > Ruby SDK and Gems and running the debugger, I'm still receiving this error:

`Error running testa: Failed to Install Gems. Following gems were not installed: /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/rb/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta3.gem: Error installing ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta3.gem: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb Installing base gem You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.`

Does anyone know how to fix this using rbenv?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest selecting the version of Ruby you wish to use via the command line and running a `bundle install` or `sudo bundle install` there.

This question may also help you.

[Installing gem or updating RubyGems fails with permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error)