# How to fix gem permission error after installing rbenv?

Tags: ruby, shell, rubygems

I was trying to install Sinatra and I kept on getting this error: `You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory`

Thanks to "[Installing gem or updating RubyGems fails with permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error)" I installed rbenv. I followed the [guide](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions) and set my global ruby version, etc. but I continue to get the same error when I try to install gems. When I run `gem environment` the installation directory for RubyGems is still the system Ruby directory.

Should I update `GEM_PATH?` Since the rbenv guide doesn't mention anything about that, something makes me think that there is still a problem with my rbenv installation.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Does it work if you use `sudo`?

Comment: i guess you have to use chmod for Gems directory

Comment: Don't use `chmod` blindly. See the selected answer to the linked question.

Comment: Run `gem env` and copy, then paste, the output into your question, formatted appropriately for readability. Don't use "edited" or "updated" tags, as we can see what changed whenever a question or answer is modified.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing us the commands you're using but it smells like you're using `sudo` to install Sinatra. Don't do that with rbenv or RVM managed Rubies.

Just as in [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error?noredirect=1&lq=1), using rbenv or RVM allows you have one or more Rubies in your user-space where you can modify them all you want. That means you don't need to use `sudo`, just use `gem install ...`.

An alternate problem you could be having is you set your global Ruby to be `system`, which is the version installed by Apple for their use, and which you don't want to modify unless you understand why it's there and what they're using it for. *IF* you have to change it then `sudo` would be appropriate but, with rbenv or RVM managing Rubies in your user-space there's really no reason to.

Do NOT use `chmod` to change the ownership of the vendor installed gems; Again, that's for Apple's use so have fun with the local Rubies instead and leave Apple's alone.

Comment: I hadn't used chmod or sudo per your instructions from the question I linked to. Upon restarting Terminal, things were working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I quit Terminal and upon reopening, things were working correctly. Probably a good thing to try if you're stuck and are sure you've followed instructions correctly. It's not explicitly mentioned in the material I read but I believe is a good practice in general.