# no write permissions when trying to install gem, /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory. RVM is installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems

would love help just learning how to deal with all these gems and having issues installing anything with 'gem install x'. I've read everywhere that its not the best practice to use 'sudo'.

-facts-

gem install cucumber   returns '`You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.`'

which gem   returned `/usr/bin/gem`

gem env     returned

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/username/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

I have rvm installed but returns -

`No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'`

Not sure what to do, would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

You need root/administrator permissions to write to / and its subdirectories. You can't install anything without using sudo or su. Your question or a similar one was answered here: [Installing gem or updating RubyGems fails with permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error?rq=1)