# Can't use "gem update --system" with rbenv

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to run:

```
gem update --system
```

But I get back.

```
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-2.6.12.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I am using `.zhrc` for my shell.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/installing-gem-or-updating-rubygems-fails-with-permissions-error) seems to relate but I added what was prescribed to my .zhrc file and it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE MAY 23rd**

I tried:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
```

But now when running:

```
gem update --system

Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.6.12
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-2.6.12
Installing RubyGems 2.6.12
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
```

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Ruby/Gems/` did not work?

Comment: @whodini9 I thought you weren't supposed to use `sudo`
?

Comment: I think the general recommendation is to not use a sudo with the `gem` command itself, because this installs the gem **as root**. Either way the shell that you are in does not have write access to the gems folder... `chown` will fix that.

Comment: @whodini9 Thanks, but now I get what I updated above...

Comment: I would try the same chown command for `/Library/Ruby/Site` I don't have a good answer for why this is happening, are you possibly using a ruby manager like rbenv / rvm?

Comment: That worked, thanks my friend! Sorry for the late reply, thanks again!