# Trying to install react native but keep getting errors

Tags: react-native, terminal

I am trying to install cocapods but it is not working! What do I do?

Charlies-MBP:~ charlie$ gem install -n /usr/local/bin ffi cocapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
Charlies-MBP:~ charlie$

I tried brew install ruby but nothing is showing up, I am just utterly stuck because theyre is nothing that can show up on the terminal.

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/697249) may help

Comment: This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607193/how-to-install-a-gem-or-update-rubygems-if-it-fails-with-a-permissions-error)