# Getting user groups in php

Tags: php

In PHP (and Linux), I am able to get the list of users that belong to a given group by using `posix_getgrnam()`, but I would like to go on the opposite way. That means, I would like to get the list of groups to which a given user belongs. How can I do it?

Comment: Use `posix_getgroups`

Comment: @kainaw That gets the groups of the current process, it doesn't take a username.

Comment: I don't think POSIX has a function like this, so there's nothing for PHP to call to do it.

Comment: Yes. Posix is limited to the running process. The system itself allows it, but then you have system dependent code. For example, you can grab the output of `grep username /etc/group | cut -d: -f3` to get a list of group IDs from a standard linux/unix system.

Comment: @kainaw you don't need to manipulate /etc/group, a linux system should have a groups command.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350141/how-to-find-out-what-group-a-given-user-has

Comment: @Devon Correct. Linux has a groups command. For this need, I prefer to hit the file. The output of groups is formatted as `username : group1 group2 group3`. The output of the grep/cut command I used is just each group on a separate line. Combined with exec, you can easily end up with an array of group names.

Answer (score 0):

**[shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)** + [How to find out what group a given user has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350141/how-to-find-out-what-group-a-given-user-has)

No built in functions for getting groups of a user.

Comment: That's how I do today... But I was wondering if I could use any PHP native function instead. Isn't the shell_exec approach much slower?

Comment: Slower than native functions, sure, but noticeable?  Probably not unless you are running this command thousands of times.

Answer (score 0):

use stats function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

```
$stat = stat($filename);
echo $stat['gid'];
```